# Worksheet Change Event - Hidden Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty new to excel VBA and I believe the following code I need would be quite simplistic however I have had very limited exposure to Worksheet_Change events.

I would like a macro to run when a cell changes its value. (Please see attached picture for more info)

I believe a normal Macro code would look something similar to the below however not sure how to incorporate this into a worksheet change macro

```
If range("E6").value = 5 then 
Columns("CG:ES").hidden = false
Columns("CG:ES").Hidden = true
else
if range("E6").value = 6 then 
Columns("CG:ES").hidden = false
Columns("CT:ES").hidden = true
else
if range("E6").value = 7 then 
Columns("CG:ES").hidden = false
Columns("DG:ES").hidden = true
else
if range("E6").value = 8 then 
Columns("CG:ES").hidden = false
Columns("DT:ES").hidden = true
else
if range("E6").value = 9 then 
Columns("CG:ES").hidden = false
Columns("EG:ES").hidden = true
else
if range("E6").value = 10 then 
Columns("CG:ES").hidden = false

end if 
end if
end if
end if 
end if 

End sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes your nested If statements for a [Select Case statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278665.aspx). This provides a little more readability and should prove easy to expand if the need arises.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Columns("CG:ES").Hidden = False
        Select Case Range("E6").Value2
            Case 5
                Columns("CG:ES").Hidden = True
            Case 6
                Columns("CT:ES").Hidden = True
            Case 7
                Columns("DG:ES").Hidden = True
            Case 8
                Columns("DT:ES").Hidden = True
            Case 9
                Columns("EG:ES").Hidden = True
        End Select
    End If

bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Events and screen updating are turned off during processing. The former isn't absolutely necessary but the latter should reduce screen 'flash'.

The [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro goes into the worksheet code page accesed by right-clicking the worksheet name tab and choosing View Code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Address = "$E$6" Then
       ' your logic here by switching on Target.Value
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Often `Target` could be more than a single cell, one of which might be $E$6.

Comment: @jeeped agree, mainly when doing a copy.paste, right?

Comment: Primarily yes but also Fill Down (or Right) and Ctrl+Enter to block fill a selection among others.